Unable to erase "encrypted volume password"
I use 3 encrypted disks as Time Machine backups. For a reason that I ignore, suddenly one of the volumes/disks started to ask for the encryption passphrase. I entered it and set it to be remembered. However, next time I booted the Mac, the passphrase entry was requested again.
I went on to check if there was an issue at the Keychain Access level. Lo and behold, the volume/disk asking for the passphrase appears 3 times (the passphrase is the same in all 3 occurrences).
Obviously, I tried to erase them either by selecting them and pressing the back key or right-clicking and selecting Delete "name_of_the_volume", to no avail.
I tried to boot in safe mode and erase the Keychain Accesses from there without success.
I also tried to physically disconnect the volume and see if it changes anything, but unfortunately it did not.
Any ideas on how to get rid of the unwanted encrypted volume passwords?

System used:

macOS: Sequoia 15.1.1
Chip: Apple M3 Max

